# query json data for specific conditions

Tags: json, node.js

what is the recommended way to query json data? for example my data looks like

```
 var meetings = 
           {
             "meeting" : [
                 {
                      "subject" : "Server upgrade for data center C3W",
                      "attendees" : [
                          {
                            "name" : "Ron Edward",
                            "title": "CEO",
                            "company": "Data Solutions",
                            "confirmed" : "yes"
                          },
                          {
                            "name" : "John Steward",
                            "title": "Procurement Officer",
                            "company": "Data Solutions",
                            "confirmed" : "yes"
                          },
                          {
                            "name" : "Name 1",
                            "title": "Senior Director",
                            "company": "C1 Corporation",
                            "confirmed" : "no"
                          }

                        ]
                 }
              ]
           }
       ;
```

and i want to query like if there is any of the attendee with confirmed no value

Comment: Which programming language are you using? I'm guessing c#

Comment: i m using nodejs

Comment: I added the tag accept the edit.

Comment: And have you tried anything so far? What **specific** problem are you having?

Comment: i was looking at jsonpath jqeury. but i m doing first time so wanted to know what people recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear about whether you want to check if there exists any  attendee  who has not confirmed , or you want to find which attendees have not confirmed ? In both cases the code is almost the same with a minor difference :-

Common Code

```
function checkConfirmation(person){
    return   person.confirmed == "no"

}
```

Explantion :  This function returns true if the  if an object with property confirmed is set to no

Case I : If you only want to find whether there is a person who has not confirmed yet

```
var result  =  meetings["meeting"][0]["attendees"].some(checkConfirmation);
  console.log(result);    //  true
```

Explantion :  The "some()"  is a Javascript Array Method which checks whether any  of the member of the array fullfill the condition of the function and return Boolean  . In your case it will be true as one attendee has not confirmed yet.

Case II : If you only want to find which all persons have not confirmed .

```
var result  =  meetings["meeting"][0]["attendees"].filter(checkConfirmation);
      console.log(result);    //  [ { name: 'Name 1',title: 'Senior Director',  company: 'C1 Corporation',    confirmed: 'no' } ]
```

Explantion :  The "filter()"  is a Javascript Array Method which returns another  array{a subarray of the original}, the members which  fullfill the condition of the function   . In your case it will have one member .

A little more about these methods :-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some